# Why is UICollectionViewCell's outlet nil?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, ios8, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a custom UICollectionViewCell in Interface Builder, binded views on it to the class, and then when I want to use and set a string to the label on the string, tha label has a nil value.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView.registerClass(LeftMenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ls")
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {

    var cell: LeftMenuCollectionViewCell
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ls", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LeftMenuCollectionViewCell
    println(cell.label) // <- this is nil, why??
    cell.label.text = "asd"

    return cell
}
```

And the subclassed cell:

```
class LeftMenuCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the explicit "!" in addition to type names everywhere? Seems redundant, esp in the IBOutlets. The only place it might matter is where you dequeue the cell as LeftmenuCollectionViewCell, but you don't do it there.. Can you println or NSLog 'cell' itself?

Comment: If I remove "!" or use "?" in class definition, I get compiler error or crash. "!" is the default when you bind it.

Comment: ant the cell itself: <xxx.LeftMenuCollectionViewCell: 0x7aa7b320; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 180 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x7aa6f810>>

Comment: All outlets hooked up in IB? Do the other outlets work? Don't see any other obvious issues, sorry.

Comment: [Basic example for setting up a Collection View](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31735229/3681880)

Answer (score 339, accepted):

I am calling `self.collectionView.registerClass(LeftMenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ls")` again. **If you are using a storyboard you don't want to call this**. It will overwrite what you have in your storyboard.

If you still have the problem check wether `reuseIdentifier` is **same** in `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` **and** in `storyboard`.

Comment: Thank you! Spent more than an hour on this as was using a custom cell.

Comment: i have the same problem but never used this line of code, you have any idea why i get the same exception?

Comment: thanks. this solved it for me. i had a storyboard and i manually added a view controller. the boilerplate code included the line you mentioned. even though it seemed correct (correct identifier & class) it refused to connect the outlets. now it works. sweet!

Comment: @Dekel Maman just make sure you have setted the right custom class and module for your cell in interface builder

Comment: **If you are using a storyboard you don't want to call this. It will overwrite what you have in your storyboard.** <- This one really Help me out

Comment: Same here. Thanks a million. (As in the number of hours I might have spent tracking this down otherwise.)

Comment: Ha ha, I just searched for this and found that I had already upvoted this answer some previous time I don't remember.

Comment: GAH, what a horrible thing to have in the UICollectionViewController template!!!!! Thanks, Janos.

Comment: Apple needs to take away that bear trap! Put a comment in not to use if using storyboard!

Comment: Straight up the documentation doesn't even tell you that

Comment: What about if it is not in the storyboard? I have a custom xib and I am having this problem. If I remove the register(...) I get an exception in the AppDelegate :/

Comment: It was my fault. I was setting the datasource and the delegate before registering the cell...

Comment: whats really annoying is the code to register a cell is boiler plated in when you subclass a collection view controller

Comment: Why would registering twice cause an issue? I'm not getting that..

Answer (score 58):

Just remove this line:

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(LeftMenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ls")
```

Comment: I don't understand why this was down voted. This was the answer to my problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and should be marked accordingly by the person who asked the question.  Would also be great to understand why it works :)

Comment: Guess it was downvoted cause the question was answered in Aug'14 itself... while this answer just copies the answer again here, after several months.

Comment: But when I don't use it, it gives me error

Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:]

Comment: An explanation for why this line is not needed would be welcome. It's currently added by the Xcode boilerplate for a new collection view.

Answer (score 57):

If you are using xib, make sure that you have added this line of code to your viewdidload.

Objective C:

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
```

Swift:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName:"MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"MyCellIdentifier")
```

Comment: do you have to register both class and nib, or only nib is enough?

Comment: I just registered the nib and it solved my problems.

Comment: Looks like there's two ways to register and I was using the wrong one... collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "YourItemClassName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")
        
collectionView?.register(YourItemClassName.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")

Comment: registering the cell in the wrong way ... wasted half of my life on this shitty small error...

Answer (score 17):

Gotta register that nib guys!

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellId")
```

Answer (score 15):

Looks like there's two ways to register and I was using the wrong one the first.
I have a custom xib view so registered with the second option, and we have data!

1:

```
collectionView?.register(YourItemClassName.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")
```

2:

```
collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "YourItemClassName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, but my mistake was that I didn't delegate CollectionViewCell to be able to change the label text..

Answer (score -1):

I think that best solution is to directly use from storyboard where add a `CollectionView`, in alternative you need to remove a `CollectionViewCell` from your `CollectionView` in storyboard and register a cell with the following command:

> collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "YourItemClassName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")

Answer (score -1):

You didn't register your cell,

```
fileprivate let yourIdentifier = ""yourIdentifier"
super.viewDidLoad() {
```

//here you need to register cell
collectionView?.register(NameOfYourClass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")
}